# Overriding SearchDelegate's transition animation

Tags: flutter

I currently have an AppBar with an icon that calls the function showSearch() with my custom delegate to handle the search behavior. As of now, when you tap that icon to enter search mode, the page that appears does so using a fade-in animation. Would it be possible to animate that window so that it slides from the bottom to the top?

Here's my custom delegate code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserSearch extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  String get searchFieldLabel => 'Find other users';

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme.of(context);
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    return [
      IconButton(
        color: Colors.orange,
        iconSize: 30,
        icon: Icon(Icons.backspace),
        onPressed: () => query = '',
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    return IconButton(
      color: Colors.orange,
      iconSize: 30,
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: () => close(context, null),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildResults
    return ListView();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
    return Column();
  }
}
```

The only lead I have is overriding createAnimation() from SearchDelegate but I have no idea how I would go about implementing it.